# Better way to store video in swift 2

Tags: core-data, video-streaming, swift2

I'm wondering which is the most performing and smart approach in order to download some mp4 videos (10~20 Mb each one) downloaded from a server using swift 2 on iOS, for "offline use" matters.

The worst, imho, is embed the files in the app. If any of the movies has to be changed, the app itself has to be released as a new version on the App Store (and the app will be unpleasantly huge to be downloaded).

For example, one can download the clips and store in core data as NSData in binary data type.

Or, download the clips and store in the app documents folder.

I like a lot the core data approach, but I'm not sure that's the better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you target iOS 9+, then [On-Demand Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/EnablingODR.html) seem like the perfect solution for you.

Comment: Uhm... A very different and interesting new approach, no doubt. Not sure if is the right solution for me, since my app at start has to do something like  "checkInternetIfPresent -> checkNewUpdatesFlag -> downloadAndSubstituteFiles". So if there's no internet link, or there is any update available, old movies will be kept. For what I read about On-Demand Resources, I have to do further work instead of simply upload new files and set the "NewUpdateFlag" on my https server.